# FileUploader in SAP UI5

Tags: file-upload, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am using File Uploader to upload data, but I need to show popup message before it opens up the file browser popup.

The requirement is, if user has already edited the data on the given page but has not saved it and if he presses Upload button we need to popup the message saying "whether you want to continue without saving the current data".

Comment: Not to sideline this but why would the current data not be saved? Wouldn't it be better to let them add the document to the control but not upload it until the rest is saved as well or something?

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on wether you have event "uploadOnChange" set to true or false
If true > use event updoadStart
If false > use event change

In both you can turn off default behaviour and prevent the upload from actually starting.

Comment: Maybe its better if you just make the upload control inactive until all data is saved ?